# ASP.NET Core Email Validation with API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, email-validation

I am trying to validate an email whether it is real or fake. I am using some code but it always returns **Ok**.

This is my code:

```
public string validateEmail(string userEmail)
{
        try
        {
            string key = "xxxx";
            string email = "xxxx";
            var crmUrl = "https://app.emaillistvalidation.com/api/verifEmail?secret=" + key + "&email=" + email;
            string url = crmUrl;

            var client = new RestClient(url);
            client.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((sender, certificate, chain, policyErrors) => { return true; });

            var request = new RestRequest();
            request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            var content = response.Content;
            return content;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return default;
}
```

What is wrong here? And what can I do instead?

Comment: You say "it" always returns Ok. What is "it"? Is it your method? The call to app.emaillistvalidation.com? Why do you have an empty catch block?

Comment: @mason yes the method is returning ok always.

Comment: Why do you have an empty catch block? Have you verified if an exception is being thrown or not? How have you verified?

Comment: There is no issues with the catch block. The problem is with the api. It is returning Ok for all valid and Invalid email..

Comment: You just said the method is always returning OK. Now you're saying the API. Which is it?

Comment: "var content = response. Content;' are you sure this is the email validate result, instead of the http request execute result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to validate an email whether it is real or fake. I am
> using some code but it always returns Ok.

I have gone through the code and the API you have shared. I also register and open a demo api on `https://app.emaillistvalidation.com/api` and it's behaving as expected for both `valid` and `invalid` email. Here are my steps:

**Register on app.emaillistvalidation.com**

[image]

**My Controller Code**

```
        [Route("ValidateEmail")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ValidateEmail(string emailId)
        {
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            var data = "";

            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
            var client = new HttpClient(handler);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

            var responseFromApi = await client.GetAsync("https://app.emaillistvalidation.com/api/verifEmail?secret=" + apiSecret + "&email=" + emailId + "");
            if (responseFromApi.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                data = await responseFromApi.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               
            }

            return Ok(data);
        }
```

**Output For Valid & Invalid Email**

[image]

**Postman Direct Test**

I have also tested on Postman for `valid` email I got `ok` response and for `invalid` and `wrong` email I got `unknown` and `disable` response:

*Valid Email:*

[image]

*Wrong Email:*

[image]

*Wrong Domain:*

[image]

**Note:** Please double-check the way you are trying. You could have a look on my code and the way I have tested. It's working as expected which has been shared in the screenshots

Comment: My code was right. I was testing in wrong way. Thank you. Seeing your code I found my mistake...

Comment: Glad to assist you.